# python: make a variable equal an operator (+,/,*,-)

Tags: python, coding-style

is it possible to assign a variable a maths operator.

this is what I've currently got, just a sample (typed it in now, so dont worry about simple errors)

```
if image == "lighten":
    red_channel = red_channel + 50
else:  // image is darken
    red_channel = red_channel  - 50
```

notice how i am repeating the exact same code, with a different operator. 
Is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
if (image == "lighten"):
    operator = +
else:
    operator = - 

red_channel = red_channel operator 50
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import operator
if (image == 'lighten'):
    op = operator.add
else:
    op = operator.sub

red_channel = op(red_channel, 50)
```

Or, if you have a number of possible operations,

```
op = {
    'lighten':operator.add,
    'darken':operator.sub,
     ...
    }
red_channel = op[image](red_channel,50)
```

Comment: +1 for directly answering the OP's question and enlightening me to a useful feature.

Answer (score 2):

I like inline expressions, so:

```
red_channel += 50 if image == 'lighten' else -50
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option rather than going to that length, as long as you are only doing either positive 50 or negative 50 is:

```
red_channel = red_channel + (flag * 50)
```

The variable "flag" is either 1 or -1; thus giving you 50 or -50. This won't save a lot of code for this small example, but I use it at times when it is convenient.

Comment: I'd suggest not using `flag` because usually flags are boolean values.